# How would I create a dynamic total on field name in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My users can create any number of "Activity" objects. I need to write some code that will go through each of these "Activity" objects and count the "Hours" field based on each "ActivityType" field. Then it throws an error if the Hours total for any of the fields is over 60. (Optional: display the ActivityType that caused the error)

Example:

```
{
    "Activity1": {
        "ActivityType": "Swimming",
        "Hours": 40,
    },
    "Activity2": {
        "ActivityType": "Cycling",
        "Hours": 20,
    }
    "Activity3": {
        "ActivityType": "Cycling",
        "Hours": 50,
    }
    "Activity4": {
        "ActivityType": "Baseball",
        "Hours": 20,
    }
    "Activity5": {
        "ActivityType": "Baseball",
        "Hours": 20,
    }
}
```

Swimming Total: 40
Cycling Total: 70 <- validation error message
Baseball Total: 40

My code used to count by Person, but now it should count by Activity. This code doesn't keep a tally per Activity, but rather for all activities on the page. So the "foreach (var person in Persons)" can be changed.

```
foreach (var person in Persons.Where(x => x.IsActive == true))
    {
       if (Activities.Where(x => x.ActivityType > 0).Sum(Y => Y.Hours) > 60)
           validations.Add(string.Format("Each activity may only have up to 60 hours per week."));
    }
)
```

It should have a total per Activity, instead of the full total of 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Group By Activity and use Sum to achieve this.

For example,

```
foreach(var activity in Activities.GroupBy(x=>x.ActivityType).Select(x=> new {ActivityType=x.Key,Hours=x.ToList().Sum(c=>c.Hours)}).Where(x=>x.Hours>60))
{
    validations.Add($"Activity {activity.ActivityType} exceeds permitted limit, Total Hours Spend ={activity.Hours}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this, that uses grouping?

```
public class Person
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Activity
{
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public uint Hours { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    private const uint Threshold = 60;
    public void CheckHours(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            var grouped = (from a in person.Activities
                group a by a.ActivityType
                into groupedActivities
                    select new { Activity = groupedActivities.Key, TotalHours = groupedActivities.Sum(g => g.Hours)}).ToList();

            foreach (var group in grouped)
            {
                if(group.TotalHours > Threshold)
                    throw new Exception($"Activity {group.Activity} for person {person.Name} has exceeded the threshold!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The CheckHours method will throw an exception for any activity for a person with total hours > 60.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GroupBy to group elements with same ActivityType, and them use sum on each group. New {} is an anonymous type

```
var result = Activities.GroupBy((x) => x.ActivityType)
                       .Select((x) => new { Name = x.Key, Hours = x.Sum((z) => z.Hours) });
```

and also for your validation you can use this

```
if (!result.All((x) => x.Hours <= 60)) validations.Add(string.Format("Each activity may only have up to 60 hours per week."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses LINQ GroupBy, and includes the name of the activity that failed validation.

```cs
foreach (var activity in Activities.GroupBy(a => a.ActivityType, a => a.Hours))
{
    if (activity.Sum() > 60)
        validations.Add(string.Format($"Each activity may only have up to 60 hours per week. {activity.Key} exceeds this."));
}`
```